MSCA/UKRI Fellowship - Personal tax owed for research expenses
I have been a UKRI/MSCA fellow for a year. The university gave me personally the entire amount: both the amount for my personal salary allowance as well as for fellowship-related expenses like travel.
I expected only to pay tax on the part that is given to me directly as a living allowance/salary. Now that I am filing taxes for the year, I am finding out that I owe income tax on the entire amount, including the amount to be used for research expenses. It doesn't seem right that research expenses should be taxed as income, but because the university transferred all the funds to me it is all being taxed.
What can I do about this? Is there any way to avoid paying tax on the part of the fellowship that should not be considered my income?

Do you mean tax, paid to the government, often a percentage of one's income? Or indirect costs or overhead, the part of a grant taken by an institution to fund research support?

I mean tax paid to the government. They paid me the allowances + research expenses as a lump sum each month, not taxed at source. I had to of course file for tax myself, which I did and found out that a huge part goes in tax. I understand this for the allowances, but I thought research expenses are there to draw from for various field trips, etc. I am now unable to claim any expenses, because of the way I have been paid. Thanks

Thanks, I've rewritten to hopefully clarify, does this seem to match your intended meaning?

Thanks. Too much stress!

I would actually expect it to be deemed as taxable income initially, in case you don't disburse it (wholly or partly) for the intended purpose of research expenses. I would then expect to see a section where you claim the disbursed expenses (with appropriate documentary proof) thereby reducing the income back to what it would have been if the institution had only paid your salary.
So are you sure the tax form doesn't have a section where you prove the actual expenses, thereby reducing your effective income?

I'd just like to add that it is super unusal for the university to pass money for research expenses on a fellowship directly on to the fellow. In fact, I think it is so unusal that it may well be against UKRI terms and conditions (althoguh I don't know that for certain).

You will (I think - I'm not a tax professional!) need to pay tax on the total sum you receive, but then you can deduct eligible expenditures on your tax return, and get the tax refunded. See https://www.gov.uk/tax-relief-for-employees for more detail. If I remember correctly, you do not need to itemise individual expenditures on the tax return, but you should be able to provide this information if HMRC decide to audit you.
Perhaps worth adding: from HMRC's perspective there is no distinction between your salary and the travel budget -- they are both income. So you can 'underspend on travel' in one tax year and 'overspend' in the next. However, if your income has changed significantly from year to year (e.g. because you were only employed for part of the tax year) you may find that while you paid tax at 20%, you get reimbursed at 40% (free money glitch!). Or vice versa.
Overall, you may end up losing a bit of your travel budget to HMRC. However, you are getting complete freedom to organise your own travel plans. In the alternative (and more usual) scenario where the university manages your travel funds, you would typically have to organise travel through the university travel agents, which usually turns out to be both annoying and expensive.

Thanks. But I am not paying tax in the UK. So none of these apply. And I can't claim expenditure AT ALL. So my travel budget is halved and I won't get any refund. This was after all calculations.

@MichelleAssay You need to include that information in your post, then; since you mention UKRI I think anyone is going to assume UK. How can we possibly help you with tax if you don't even tell us what country you pay tax in?

I think it behooves OP to get professional advice. Tax matters never go away, and the only way to make sure this doesn't bite you some time in the future, is to get it understood and sorted officially right now.

It has already bit me for this year. I've been served a huge tax bill and had to pay. I doubt I can get anything back even if we resolve the matter. Unfortunately it seems I just was served a bad deal and didn't realise it until it was too late. But I just want someone to point me towards T and Cs that indicate research expenses are reimbursed. Thanks

You could ask for advice from MSCA or the university's finance office. You could also ask the tax authority though they might be less easy to deal with. I agree that it sounds strange that this would be taxed.

"I agree that it sounds strange that this would be taxed."... In my opinion, it should be taxed unless disbursed with proof that the spend was fellowship related. What if the OP got to the end of the fellowship without spending any of it.....

@user95861 I don't have experience with this fellowship but at least in the US the way it would work is that research expenses are never given directly to the grant recipient, they're either paid directly by the institution or personal funds are used initially but then reimbursed through a channel that does not involve any tax.

Exactly! I shouldn't have been paid this expenses in the first place. I should have just been reimbursed. If I don't spend them, they roll over.

Yes, you are all right. But my advice to ask the various offices and authorities still stands. OP doesn't seem to have asked any of those people yet.
